# Bluetooth not starting on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome

When i turn on my laptop the Bluetooth won't come up. Even Bluetooth settings won't work. i had to reboot evertime to turn Bluetooth on. Can i have a solution for this. I'm using hp pavilion notebook g6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you have an issue with your bluetooth drivers. Have a look here how to install bluetooth drivers on Ubuntu and other common bluetooth problems that you might be facing.
https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.